# How can I use tokens in node-pages in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I know that tokens (token module) can be used to fill in tokens.

But for my articles (of node type page) how can I use tokens so that my site's name etc. can replaced automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Token Filter module](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter).  It will allow you to use tokens within your node body field.

From the module page:

> In the text where you use that input filter you can use substitution tokens with 
>   [token global site-name] etc. You can use the global context, the user context and any
>   custom context available. You need to enable the Token Filter for any of your existing
>   filter types first.

For instructions on using this module, see the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/token_filter.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/README.txt)

Comment: What about the node title? Is there a solution to use Tokens in the title field of a node?

Comment: Yes, for that you can use [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)

Comment: Great! Do you know if there is a one-off solution for things like Panel pages? Since those are not really distinct content types that I would set the default auto_nodetitle for.

For instance, I have a custom page made with Panels, and I'd like its title to be something like "Welcome back, [site:current-user]"

Comment: I thought Tokens were already available in that area? Anyway, I don't have in depth Panels experience, your best bet is to create a new question explaining what you are trying to do and then other people will have a chance to answer as well:)

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7**

Install and enable [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module and enable 'Replace tokens' filter e.g. for Full HTML text format.

For testing may edit any node and just type [site:name] to see if that works.

For Help, as admin go to Help->Token and you will find all the tokens you can use (/admin/help/token).